# Modelo relacional para login de usuário

Tags: modelagem, modelo-relacional

Preciso fazer um sistema simples de cadastro de marcas, porém gostaria que a pessoa que for cadastrar uma nova marca esteja logada no sistema, estou com uma dificuldade em onde encaixar a tabela de login no meu modelo relacional.

Se tiver alguma coisa errada no meu modelo, podem me avisar e me ajudar a colocar a tabela de Login?

Aqui esta meu modelo:

[image: Modelo]

Comment: O que seria esse *login*?

Comment: Esse login seria para permitir o usuário ter acesso ao cadastramento de marcas, ou seja, se ele não efetuar o login, ele não pode alterar nada, somente visualizar as marcas cadastradas

Comment: O "login" é uma operação, a operação de logar no sistema. Nesse caso ele não precisa de uma tabela, a tabela usuário já possui os dados necessários para realizar o "login".

Comment: Mas você já tem isso no usuário.

Comment: E como eu faria a relação da tabela usuário com as outras?

Comment: Que outras? Não consigo ver relação alguma direta, pelo menos de acordo com sua descrição.

Comment: Geralmente quando se fala em uma tabela login, é para salvar as datas que o usuário foi autenticado, também pode ser salvo informações como IP de origem e dispositivo usado, para fins de segurança

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem conhecer os requisitos reais não tem muito como ajudar, são sempre eles que definirão o que é certo ou errado. Se tivesse uma só forma de fazer então tudo já estaria pronto e ninguém precisaria fazer de novo. Mesmo em um exercício ele precisa definir bem o que quer.

Abstratamente, dentro do meu conhecimento, não vejo porque existir uma tabela de *login*, afinal já tem essa informação na tabela de usuários.

O *login* é uma operação bastante isolada e não costuma ter relação com outras partes. Você faz uma autenticação ali, recebe permissão (em sistemas mais sofisticados pode ter tabelas de permissões) e acabou o uso dela. A aplicação deve tratar isso adequadamente. As demais tabelas nada tem a ver com o *login* que é um mecanismo da aplicação, as outras tabelas fazem parte do domínio do problema em si. A não ser que essa tabela esteja aí por outro motivo.

Além disso em geral os mais experientes dizem que não faz sentido nomear uma tabela com um prefixo `tbl`, é informação redundante que diminui a legibilidade.

Me parece que está querendo criar relacionamento a todo custo mesmo que eles não sejam necessários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).